# 'rospack Error: package 'rosserial_arduino' not found' when trying to run 'rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py' when it IS there

Tags: arduino, ros

Sorry if the title is a little confusing. I'm trying to get rosserial installed as to allow communication between ROS and my arduino. I was following the guide and nothing would install rosserial aside from the catkin method and saved in my catkin_ws folder in my home tab. The next step was to run -

```
 cd <sketchbook>/libraries

 rm -rf ros_lib

 rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py
```

Running these commands in either home/usr/arduino-1.8.8/libraries or home/usr/arduino/libraries doesn't work either, it just throws at me 'rospack Error: package 'rosserial_arduino' not found'. I even manually moved the rosserial_arduino file (the one with make_libraries.py) and tried again but still doesn't work. I'm new to this so i've exhausted everything I can think of but hope someone a bit more savvy can help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by moving all the rosserial files to trash and then running the sudo apt-get install method. I did try it first but it just wouldn't work, but did now for whatever reason...